# How to replace two curly brackets with strings?

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to turn this: `'text {n} text {2} text'` into this `'text first text second text'`

I thought it was easy:

```
function setLocales (string, first, second) {
  string.replace(/\{(.+?)\/(.+?)\}/g, function (first, label second) {
    // What to do here?
  }
  return string
}

// usage: setLocales(string, 'first', 'second')
```

But I was wrong. And I'm stuck in the middle of the function.

How to complete this function?

Comment: Uh, why are you matching on a slash that separates two groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of using a function with String.prototype.replace on [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). Your callback function parameters are wrong; the first parameter is the whole matched substring (matched by the whole regex).

The easiest and most reliable way would be to match one "{something}" at a time and loop for each replacement you have in store:

```
/* Pseudo */
for (let replacement of ['first', 'second']) {
    str.replace("{.*}", replacement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `replace` targets the first find, you can use it like that:

```js
function setLocales(s) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    s = s.replace(/{.+?}/, arguments[i]);
  }
  console.log(s);
}

setLocales('text {n} text {2} text', 'first', 'second');
```